# Android Darken Screen and show Progress

Tags: android, progress-bar

I am uploading/downloading some data in my application using AsyncTask. What I want is that, when the AsyncTask is running, the whole screen should get dimmed/disabled and a ProgressBar would be shown in the middle of the screen as long as the task is running.

Something like this
[image: Something like this]

Any ideas / suggestions are most welcome. 
Really need to implement it in my application!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the picture the dialogue is a `Dialogue Activity`. You can search on Goolge how to implement `dialogue Activity`  :)

Answer (score 1):

the default "Dialog" theme does just that. You can do this

- launch a new activity with the Dialog theme
- the xml of that activity must have no background image/colour
- show your dialog in the new activity
- finish the activity, when the dialog is dismissed acc to your program logic